# what are the specifics of setting up PHP so that integers will be 64-bit?

Tags: php, 64-bit

I think the general idea of PHP being able to have common integer 64-bit (as opposed to use math packages) is to use 64-bit hardware and 64-bit PHP.  Does someone know the specifics?  For example, won't the Core2Duo machine be able to support it?  What about the 32-bit version of OS like Vista or OS X, can they support it too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're on a 64 bit OS, and install 64 bit binaries, you're good to go.

e.g., my dev box is centos, and I installed php-*.x86_64 packages.

When I run:

```
$ php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
```

I get:

```
9223372036854775807
```

If 64 bit binaries aren't available for your platform, apparently there's only one configure option you need to remember while compiling: [–with-libdir=/lib64](http://www.blackbeagle.com/web-hosting/compiling-php-on-a-64-bit-system/)

If you're using windows, there are [plenty of resources out there](http://www.google.com/#q=php+64+bit+compile+windows) re: 64 bit PHP on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

- A 32bit OS can't support 64bit software.
- Core2Duo is 64bit (and can also run in 32bit mode)
- There is a [PHPx64 Project](http://www.fusionxlan.com/PHPx64.php) for windows x64, but I.m not sure if it will give you 64bit integers.

Comment: what is the official 64-bit version of PHP?  php.net doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: Jian: there isn't an official 64 bit windows build.  Compile your own, or use PHPx64.

Answer (score 1):

You must have 64-bit hardware and 64-bit OS to run PHP in 64-bit. Compiling PHP from source should detect this automatically. If you're installing binaries, they must be compiled as 64-bit, which evidently aren't available from php.net but are available elsewhere on the Internet.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php/864402).

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't available (from official sources) in 64bit versions.