# Conversion to 64 bit int

Tags: php, 64-bit

So I am working in PHP to convert a Steam Id, which many of you may be familiar with. I have the following steam ID:

```
STEAM_0:1:1514332
```

Now, I need to convert this to the 64 bit version, which is also the community ID. After browsing Steams official release on this here: http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID and after also looking many places online, I have found the following method works for this:

```
Let X,Y, and Z be defined by the Steam ID: STEAM_X:Y:Z
SteamCommunityID = (Z*2) + 76561197960265728 + Y
```

So it works! However, where seems to be a mismatch between my ACTUAL community ID, and the one I am generating

```
Actual:        76561197963294393
PHP generated: 76561197963294000
```

When reversing the equasion, to get my steam id from the community id, I get: `1514335.5`

Here is a simple example of the php in question:

```
//STEAM_0:1:1514332

$a = (1514332 * 2) + 76561197960265728 + 1;
echo $a; //76561197963294000
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might be running into your platform-specific INT_MAX. do echo(PHP_INT_MAX); and post results.

Comment: Also, try this: echo bcadd((z*2), 76561197960265728 + Y);

Comment: 2147483647. This mean I can only use 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP don't have 64bit int on 32-bit binary. It is using floating point here.  see [how to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058)

The question include links to [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), which can be used for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use the following code and it works perfectly for splitting the Steam ID and working out the 64-bit community ID:

```
$split = explode(":", $steamid); // STEAM_?:?:??????? format

$x = substr($split[0], 6, 1);
$y = $split[1];
$z = $split[2];

$w = ($z * 2) + 0x0110000100000000 + $y;
```

$w will be the correctly formatted ID. I thought this may be helpful since I found this trying to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the issue. I'm using xampp on windows and its using the 32bit version of php but i just finished making a working script :) it can convert 64bit steamid's to 32bit and back have a mess with it.

```
<?php
//Starting 64bit steamid
$steamid = "76561198086186258";
echo "Original 64bit steamid: $steamid";

//64bit steamid to 32bit below
$authserver = bcsub($steamid, '76561197960265728') & 1;
$authid = (bcsub($steamid, '76561197960265728')-$authserver)/2;
$steamid = "STEAM_0:$authserver:$authid";
echo "<br/>32bit steamid: $steamid";

//32bit steamid to 64bit below
$id = explode(":", $steamid);
$authserver = $id[1];
$steamid64 = $id[2];
$steamid64 = $steamid64 * 2;
$steamid64 = bcadd($steamid64, 61197960265728);
if ($authserver == 1){$steamid64 = $steamid64 + 1;};
$steamid64 = "765$steamid64";
echo "<br/>new 64bit steamid: $steamid64";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the BC Math PHP extension. Here is a snippet:

```
//STEAM_0:1:1514332

$a = bcadd(bcadd((1514332 * 2), 76561197960265728), 1);
echo $a; //76561197963294393
```

Comment: Did you get the same result from this? Because the `76561197963294000
` is still the incorrect calculation. Unfortunately this is not working for any steam id conversions.

Comment: No i "miss copy/pasted" your comment :) I get: 76561197963294393

Answer (score 0):

try to add `(string)` before these calculations

```
$a = (string) (1514332 * 2) + 76561197960265728 + 1;
```

and it will work always;

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/92686.php)

response: 76561197963294393

Comment: @Headspin: it's replica of your "actual ID"

Comment: I see your example working. Why would I still be getting the same incorrect result though?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [BCMath](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) extension, you can do the following:

```
bcadd(bcadd(bcmul('1514332', '2'), '76561197960265728'), 1)
```

Which is a conversion of the equation above. It returns a string and not an int, thus avoiding the 32bit int problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. The formula is correct (using a calculator I get the 'actual' number).

There must be either a rounding or calculating issue or a simple OS limit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Very old topic but just wanted to share how I solved it since I had 32bit PHP and no possibility of using BCMath on my host. (thanks SiPlus for solution)

Here's a snippet:

```html
# Convert Steam ID to Steam64 ID
$idParts = explode(':', $tradeOwnerSteamId32);
$authServer = intval($idParts[1]);
$accountNumber = intval($idParts[2]);
$tradeOwnerSteamId64 = (string) $accountNumber * 2 + $authServer;

//And using it in URL

$depositorInventory = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/[U:1:$tradeOwnerSteamId64]/inventory/json/730/2"), true);
```