# Function returning incorrect result

Tags: php

I am trying to do exactly what this guy is doing:
[Conversion to 64 bit int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074978/conversion-to-64-bit-int)

except one thing: my function keeps on returning just '76561197960265728'

```
function getFriendId($steamId)
{
$split = explode(":", $steamid); // STEAM_?:?:??????? format

$x = substr($split[0], 6, 1);
$y = $split[1];
$z = $split[2];
$w = bcadd(bcadd(bcmul($z, '2'), '76561197960265728'), $y);
return $w;
}
```

How is this happening? I have tried with and without bcadd/bcmul and same results.

Oh, and the max int size for my platform is 9223372036854775807 if that is relevant. I did the math and the SteamID shouldn't be bigger than that...

Comment: Your title seems to be unrelated to your question.  Perhaps you need to change it?

Comment: When you debugged it, what were the values of `$x`, `$y` and `$z`? I guess `$z` was 0.

Comment: @Charles it saved the title from a different draft, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

---

Adjust your [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to [`E_NOTICE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).  PHP will *notice* you why `$z` is 0.

<sub>You did debug your code, before you asked here, did you?</sub>