# How to get the normal Steam ID from the Steam ID 64 using c#

Tags: c#, steam

Steams Open ID only returns the Steam ID 64:

For example: `76561198025336843`

How can I convert it to the real Steam ID?

For example: `STEAM_0:1:32535557`

Is there a way to obtain the Information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is absolutly possible. The real Steam ID can be calculated from the 64-bit integer (`long`).

Basicly we can extract the following two informations using [some calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32808242/2441442):

- The authentification Server
- The authentification Id

With this informations, we can concatenate the Steam ID. Here are two Utility methods for it:

```
public static string GetSteamId(string steamId64)
{
    return GetSteamId(long.Parse(steamId64));
}

public static string GetSteamId(long steamId64)
{
    var authserver = (steamId64 - 76561197960265728) & 1;
    var authid = (steamId64 - 76561197960265728 - authserver) / 2;
    return $"STEAM_0:{authserver}:{authid}";
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = GetSteamId("76561198025336843");
//result: STEAM_0:1:32535557
```