# maximum upload file size in php 5.3

Tags: file-upload, php

What is the maximum file upload size allowed in the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` configuration options (in PHP 5.3)?

Comment: the maximum file size we can configure in post_max_size and upload_max_filesize variables in php 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual entry about *`post_max_size`*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

> **Note:**
>
> PHP allows shortcuts for bit values, including K (kilo), M (mega) and G (giga).
>   PHP will do the conversions automatically if you use any
>   of these. Be careful not to exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit (if
>   you're using 32bit versions) as it will cause your script to fail.

Your limit could be 32bit signed integer limit.  ~2,147,483,647 bytes on a 32 bit version. See the [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/reserved.constants#constant.php-int-max) constant to get the value for your system:

> **PHP_INT_MAX** ([integer](http://php.net/language.types.integer))
>
> The largest integer supported in this build of PHP. Usually int(2147483647). Available since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5

Related:

- [How to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/864058/367456)

Comment: So that means though it is php 5.2 or 5.3 the maximum size is 2,147,483,647 bytes for 32 bit versions right?

Comment: yep. It basically takes an input of type `integer`. So depending on your php platform, the max value will differ. See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Is there any way that I can install 64 bit php version on ubuntu 9.10 server?

Comment: If you're compiling it, then the process is the same. I'm sorry I should have been clearer. I meant, on a 64bit platform(your os and hardware) the `interger` max value will differ from the 32bit platform. If you're able to compile php from source, then your integer value should automatically be to the tune of `9e18` on a 64bit platform. Take care when installing from binaries, you'll need a 64bit version.

Comment: Yes My server is a ubuntu 9.10 64 bit one. Any recommendation giude for compiling php source on ubuntu 64 bit server? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is no real limit set by PHP to post_max_size or upload_max_filesize. However both values must be smaller than memory_limit (also you can modify this). Anyway, as values use something (a lot) smaller than your RAM. A hacker may attempt to send a very large file that will consume completely your system resources. To upload large file is better to use an FTP server.

Comment: Yes that is the main issue I talked with my client. But he wants this to be done. Thanks for your input