# PHP Array: Is there a way to force all array keys to be string?

Tags: php, arrays, overflow

Edit:  I have made a demo to my problem: http://codepad.org/ByNdAdCI

We use the following logic to set our arrays in 32 bit php:

```
    private function formatAvailableOptions($availableOptions) {
    $optionsAsArray = array();
    foreach($availableOptions as $option){
        $optionsAsArray[$option["entity_id"]] = $option["name"];
    }
    return $optionsAsArray;
}
```

Problem:

1. The `$option["entity_id"]` has grown too big to fit in 32 bit int, and as a result overflow when `$optionsAsArray` gets created.  For example

   $optionsAsArray[2147483648] = "hi";

becomes

```
$optionsAsArray[-2147483648] = "hi";
```

I need the index to be 2147483648 as it's tied to ids in the database

1. This code is already shipped to the client, and the logic is used in many places that makes it infeasible to modify every single instance to

   `$optionsAsArray[strVal(2147483648)] = "hi";`

to make it run properly by using string type as key to associative array.

What is the best solution in this case?  Is there a global config option for me to force all php arrays to use string as keys to get around this problem?

Comment: Your problem must be somewhere else http://codepad.org/WReVhjTF PHP automatically converts `int` to `float`, if they exceed their limits. Probably the values already came in as `-1`. However, if they overflow, they will _not_ become `-1`, but they will become `- PHP_INT_MAX + 1`, what is just another evidence, that your problem must be somewhere else. Therefore this is a (maybe important) bug and with this in mind you should consider to ship an update to your costumers.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I was confused.  I played with code on codepad to better demonstrate my overflow issue:  http://codepad.org/ByNdAdCI

Comment: I can duplicate your problem on an old Ubuntu 8.x server running PHP 5.2.4 32-bit, but not on anything with PHP 5.3 or higher running 64-bit.  In what form does your input data arrive?  Perhaps you could preprocess it with `sed` to put quotes around your keys?

Comment: @ghoti Of course you can't reproduce it on 64bit systems: `echo PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: I can pre-cast the keys to string and that would fix the issue, I was hoping not having to do that as a lot of code duplicates this stupid logic.  But from the suggestions I'm seeing I would either have to 1.  Upgrade all clients to 64 bits or 2.  Roll fix out for dozens of files : P

Comment: @KingCrunch - of course you can't.  But sometimes, explaining things in more detail with real-world examples helps people understand.  Chill, dude, and don't be so patronizing.  It doesn't help, and it doesn't encourage others to help.

Comment: @Rosemary Thyme upgrading all clients to 64 bits will solve not only this, but also other potential issues that may arise from the mismatch of integer datatypes between the DB and PHP

Comment: @ghoti Oh, I'm calm :) But the 64bit-thing was just too obvious ^^

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that it doesn't like floats as keys ;) So the type cast to float fails. You already mentioned your solution in the question (`strVal($var)`, or `(string) $var`, or just `"$var"`). If your customers run PHP in 64bit (what they should ;)) they don't see any difference. Because this is obviously a bug you should consider to fix it and publish an update to your customers. There is no option, or setting, that converts a 32bit installation into a 64bit one on the fly.

Comment: I am investigating upgrading to 64-bit php, however on the windows platform, it seems that the underlying compiler everyone uses (Visual C++ 9) doesn't use 8 byte ints.  A comment on this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php suggests that having 64 bit ints on windows is impossible

Comment: Must say: Don't know. I only develop on linux, because less difficulties (like this one ;))