# How to unpack unsigned long long in php?

Tags: php

I need to read a packet, little endian, long long(64 bit)
this works fine:

```
echo unpack("V", $packet) . unpack("V", $packet);
```

but why this does not work?

```
echo unpack("V2", $packet);
```

Comment: Your version of PHP has no 64 bit support

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php

Comment: @Max I tried echo PHP_INT_MAX; and it returned 9223372036854775807. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
      echo unpack("V2", $packet, $packet >> 32);
```