# Same function in javascript and php giving different output

Tags: php, javascript

Function in javascript:

```
function int64add(dst, x, y)
{
    var w0 = (x.l & 0xffff) + (y.l & 0xffff);
    var w1 = (x.l >>> 16) + (y.l >>> 16) + (w0 >>> 16);
    var w2 = (x.h & 0xffff) + (y.h & 0xffff) + (w1 >>> 16);
    var w3 = (x.h >>> 16) + (y.l >>> 16) + (w2 >>> 16);
    dst.l = (w0 & 0xffff) | (w1 << 16);
    dst.h = (w2 & 0xffff) | (w3 << 16);
}
```

I converted this javascript to PHP as:
Function in PHP:

```
function int64add($dst, $x, $y)
{
    $w0 = ($x->l & 0xffff) + ($y->l & 0xffff);
    $w1 = ($x->l >> 16) + ($y->l >> 16) + ($w0 >> 16);
    $w2 = ($x->h & 0xffff) + ($y->h & 0xffff) + ($w1 >> 16);
    $w3 = ($x->h >> 16) + ($y->l >> 16) + ($w2 >> 16);
    $dst->l = ($w0 & 0xffff) | ($w1 << 16);
    $dst->h = ($w2 & 0xffff) | ($w3 << 16);
}
```

these two function return different output for same input. Tried searching over internet but couldn't find anything. Please help!

**In JS:**

Input:

dst:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

x:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

y:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

returns:

```
int64{
    h=-736899889,
    l=-411463152
}
```

**IN PHP:**

Input:

dst:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

x:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

y:

```
int64{
    h=1779033703,
    l=-205731576
}
```

returns:

```
int64{
    h=-736899891,
    l=-411463152
}
```

**Class int64 in php:**

```
class int64{
    var $h;
    var $l;
    function int64($h,$l){
        $this->h=$h;
        $this->l=$l;
    }
}
```

**Function int64 in js:**

```
    function int64(h,l){
        this.h=h;
        this.l=l;
    }
```

**I want PHP to give output as Javascript. (Javascript is the correct one)**

Comment: What types are $dst, $x, $y ? (objects, arrays, strings..)

Comment: Why at the PHP at last 2 lines you have $dst. ?

Where is the return ?

Comment: so you don't want to show these outputs?

Comment: $dst->l - is editing the class's var and is returning from there.

Comment: maybe the answer will be there is no int64 type in javascript? all integers are 32 bits.

Comment: Can you tell what you are passing to dst x and y?

Comment: Have you tried passing `$dst` by reference? In the function signature, use `function int64add(&$dst, $x, $y)`

Comment: Since you seem to be adding numbers, I am sure you know which is giving the correct result. Kindly share that here.

Comment: I gave all the inputs and outputs, please try. @steveukx, yes, I tried that

Comment: Signed numbers are handled in a special way! Unless I am grossly overlooking something, your code does not have any case to handle sign bits (The MSB) See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: I want PHP to give output as Javascript. (Javascript is the correct one)

Comment: why am I not surprised that it's the PHP version that's "wrong"...

Comment: If you are willing to ditch this function and use PHP extensions this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php A good suggestion there is to use BCMath or GMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're not handling the `>>>` operator properly in PHP. You should make sure to clear the higher bits using `& 0xffff` after the right shift operation:

```
$w0 = ($x->l & 0xffff) + ($y->l & 0xffff);
$w1 = (($x->l >> 16) & 0xffff) + (($y->l >> 16) & 0xffff) + (($w0 >> 16) & 0xffff);
$w2 = ($x->h & 0xffff) + ($y->h & 0xffff) + ($w1 >> 16);
$w3 = (($x->h >> 16) & 0xffff) + (($y->l >> 16) & 0xffff) + (($w2 >> 16) & 0xffff);
```

Doing that gave the same values for me, but they were different from yours; maybe your input values weren't all the same (copy paste mistake?)

```
object(int64)#1 (2) {
  ["h"]=>
  int(1573309647)
  ["l"]=>
  int(-411463152)
}
```

As others have mentioned, I would seriously consider using GMP or BCMath.

Comment: could you check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029288/javascript-and-phps-similar-function-gave-different-output