# Javascript and PHP's similar function gave different output

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?
    class int64{
        var $h;
        var $l;
        function int64($h, $l)
        {
            $this->h = $h;
            $this->l = $l;
        }
    }
    function int64rrot(int64 $dst, int64 $x, $shift)
    {
        $dst->l = ($x->l >> $shift) | ($x->h << (32-$shift));
        $dst->h = ($x->h >> $shift) | ($x->l << (32-$shift));
        print_r($dst);
    }
    $a =  new int64(1779033703,-205731576);
    $b =  new int64(1779033701,-205731572);
    int64rrot($a,$b,19);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function int64rrot(dst, x, shift)
    {
        dst.l = (x.l >>> shift) | (x.h << (32-shift));
        dst.h = (x.h >>> shift) | (x.l << (32-shift));
        console.log(dst);
    }
    function int64(h, l)
    {
      this.h = h;
      this.l = l;
    }
    a =  new int64(1779033703,-205731576);
    b =  new int64(1779033701,-205731572);
    int64rrot(a,b,19);
</script>
```

**Output in screen (by PHP:)**

```
int64 Object ( [h] => -1725854399 [l] => -393 )
```

**Output in console (by Javascript)** (Correct one):

```
int64 { h=-1725854399, l=1020051063}
```

I am trying to correct this whole day. but couldn't. What modification do I need in PHP code to get the answer as javascript?

> **I Want to get javascript output using php**

Answer (score 1):

You used a >>> operator in JavaScript. It means logical rightshift. PHP Does not have this, this is the error.

To get the same output:

Change the operator in JavaScript from '>>>' to '>>' *or*

implement a logical rightshift function in PHP.

Comment: could you try that yourself, and then give the code here, because i didn't understand what you actually mean

Comment: You would have to implement the >>> operatior in PHP. Try searching "zero rightshift" in php

Answer (score 1):

You used a `>>>` `logical rightshift` operator in JavaScript which is not available in php. thats why its causing error.

You do like this:

```
function zeroRs($a,$n){
    if($n<=0) return $a;
    $b= 0x80000000;
    return ($a >> $n) & ~($b >> ($n-1));
}
```

Now instead of `$x->l >> $shift` do `zeroRs($x->l, $shift)`. This should work!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've never saw an operator like `>>>` in JavaScript. Maybe that is the error.</strike>

There is a difference in the operator usage.

[See the MDN docs for details on `>>>` vs `>>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Instead of:

```
x.l >>> shift
```

try:

```
x.l >> shift
```