# how to handle large unique identifiers in php?

Tags: php, integer

How to validate `id` in php? I usually user `intval($_GET['id'])` however now I am dealing with large number and `intval` is returning them as `0`.

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

this is one of my numbers `95315898521642`

**Note: I want to check is a number is > 0**

Comment: Validate, as in, make sure its a number?

Comment: How large ids are you validate?

Comment: Yes, validate as make sure it is a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter_var` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if (!empty($id) && '-' != $id[0])
{
  echo 'Good!';
}
```

Comment: I want to check if value is larger than 0

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at the long datatype, see [how to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with integer numbers you can use `ctype_digit()`

Answer (score 0):

Max integer size in PHP is 9223372036854775807 for a 64 bit system and 2147483647 on a 32 bit system.

You can always try using `is_numeric()` to validate if the value is a number, or a regex such as `preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/i', $_GET['id'])`.

Comment: I am using 32bit system so my max is 2147483647 and I want to validate if then number is > 0