# Dropbox API Architecture issue

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I have a problem while using dropbox API and I have no been able to find any solutions. I am using the example code from their site and having issues.

```
<?php
require_once "../../dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("../../key.json");
$dbxConfig = new dbx\Config($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuth($dbxConfig);
list($requestToken, $authorizeUrl) = $webAuth->start('http://example.com');
?>
```

This code gives me an error and an exception on the final line. This is the exception

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK at least a 64-bit build of PHP, but it looks like we're running a 32-bit build    (PHP_INT_MAX=2147483647).  Library: "/var/dropbox/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php"' in /var/dropbox/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 /var/dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php(27): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Dropbox\autoload('Dropbox\Request...')
#2 /var/dropbox/lib/Dropbox/WebAuth.php(73): spl_autoload_call('Dropbox\Request...')
#3 /var/www/home/index.php(12): Dropbox\WebAuth->start('http://example....')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/dropbox/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php on line 15
```

I don't know what to do because I'm pretty sure I'm using a 64bit system... here is my uname output...

`Linux me 3.2.0-45-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:12:06 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any ideas or insight into why I am getting this error, or how to install a 64bit version of php...? If it helps, this is my php -v output

`root@me:/var/www/home# php -v
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:54:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the version of PHP you're using only supports 32-bit integers, but the Dropbox SDK requires 64-bit integers.

See this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/864402

Are you using Ubuntu's standard PHP package?  On my installation of Ubuntu, the standard PHP does support 64-bit integers.  Type `which php` on the command-line to see which PHP binary you're running.

Comment: the output of which php was `/usr/bin/php`.  Also it seems that the thread you linked me to was right. My output of `php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'` was `2147483647`.

Comment: Should I even mess with this problem, or should I just buy different server with a different kernel. I'll get a fresh install and try again.

Comment: The kernel shouldn't matter (besides, it looks like you're running a 64-bit kernel already).  It's how your OS decides to build and package PHP.  But yeah, try doing a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: I fixed it by getting a machine and apt-getting php again. I'm not sure why a re-installation of php on the old machine did not fix it....but oh well. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was resolved when I installed the php5-curl package. I use:

```
$php --version
```

> PHP 5.6.1 (cli)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

```
$ php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
```

> 9223372036854775807