# php 64 bit with php_int_max = 2147483647

Tags: php, windows, int

I have install WampServer 2.0 that has apache 2.4.4, mysql 5.6.12, and php 5.4.12. When I echo  PHP_INT_MAX it gave me 2147483647. I have also echo phpinfo() and the architecture indicates x64. This suppose to be not happening because my php is 64 bit right? I need my php to support 64 bit integer. I need my PHP_INT_MAX to be 9223372036854775807.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: *`long` must become `long long` in the PHP source. Then recompile! :) - have no idea if it would work as it might break things everywhere.* I hope they eventually go to a 64bit long representation. But there's pretty much nothing you can do about this. I also hope they'll go Unicode... but there's little hope.

Comment: I'm not 100% right now and too busy to look it up but `floats` in PHP are `doubles` which ARE `64bit` even on Windows, while `floats` are 32bit. So you might try to use them.

Comment: The problem now is I can't proceed with my code when I execute it because i'm trying to integrate dropbox into my website, when I run my code using dropbox sdk, it has error which state that my version of php doesn't support 64 bit integer, so I can't proceed with the integration.

Comment: can you post error  message?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=2147483647). Library: "C:\wamp\www\dropbox-sdk\Dropbox\RequestUtil.php"' in C:\wamp\www\dropbox-sdk\Dropbox\RequestUtil.php on line 15

Comment: please, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php  seems you can't have 64bit integers on windows

Comment: and IMHO, I think it's better to use library, which used string implementation for big numbers

Answer (score 10):

If you're running a windows OS, wampServer suggests you are, [this is your answer](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/55886):

> On windows x86_64, PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647. This is because in the 
>   underlying c-code, a long is 32 bit.

Note that this doesn't mean that Windows doesn't support 64bit int's: `int64_t` does exist, but it's not used by PHP AFAIK.
I've managed to come up with [this link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/integers-in-php-running-with-scissors-and-portability/), on that page, there's some code you might be able to use, to add support for 64bit ints to your code

Comment: thanks for the reply. So is there any way to solve this problem? I don't really understand what it is telling me to do with the link you gave me.

Comment: @user2615039: [there is a hacky workaround](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/integers-in-php-running-with-scissors-and-portability/), that doesn't require you to switch to linux ;)

Answer (score 4):

In the file `RequestUtil.php`, it does the following check:

```
if (strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) < 19) {
    // Looks like we're running on a 32-bit build of PHP.  This could cause problems because some of the numbers
    // we use (file sizes, quota, etc) can be larger than 32-bit ints can handle.
    throw new \Exception("The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=" . ((string) PHP_INT_MAX) . ").  Library: \"" . __FILE__ . "\"");
}
```

*You can comment it out and try hacking your way from there.*

**If I were you, I'd write my own Dropbox API implementation using strings and not integers.**

**PS**: *But this is what I do so I enjoy it :)*

Comment: thanks for the alternative solution, just hope it won't cause problems later on.

Comment: @user2615039 **It might**, *but you can at least move on with testing.* Always try to treat long integers as string and you might get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP7 - the current master http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/master/ . 64-bit builds now exploit all the capabilities of the 64-bit Windows.

Comment: "PHP 7 provides full 64-bit support. The x64 builds of PHP 7 support native 64-bit integers, LFS, memory_limit and much more."
So, all builds, not only master:
http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Yea, 7.0 was master to the time of posting :) After the GA it's now any build OFC.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox'
and comment lines 19-23 in RequestUtil.php.

Comment this section:

```
/*if (strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) < 19) {
    // Looks like we're running on a 32-bit build of PHP.  This could cause problems because some of the numbers
    // we use (file sizes, quota, etc) can be larger than 32-bit ints can handle.
    throw new \Exception("The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=" . ((string) PHP_INT_MAX) . ").  Library: \"" . __FILE__ . "\"");
}*/
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

I tried php7 and it worked:

`running php.exe -r "echo PHP_INT_MAX;"`

and it outputs `9223372036854775807`