# PHP_INT_SIZE returns 4 But my Operating System Is 64 bit

Tags: php, operating-system

My operating System is windows 7 and 64bit.
Now I run following code:

```
echo PHP_INT_SIZE;//prints 4
echo PHP_INT_MAX;//prints 2147483647
```

But I think it should be `8` and `(2^63-1)//^ represents power`

Can anyone explain me why this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php 64 bit with php\_int\_max = 2147483647](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837157/php-64-bit-with-php-int-max-2147483647)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integer size are always compiler/interpreter/platform dependent (this applies for other languages too).
In the case of PHP on Windows it does not support 64-bit integers at all, even if both the hardware and PHP are 64-bit

> On windows x86_64, PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647. This is because in the underlying c-code, a long is 32 bit.
>
> Linux on x86_64 uses a 64bit long so PHP_INT_MAX is going to be 9223372036854775807.

If you need a bigger precision you could use either [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) or [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension.

Tip: never make assumptions on the max value a type will be able to handle unless you need exactly on which php version/platform the code will run.

Comment: This isn't true for PHP 7 anymore, it was for PHP 5.6 though with the [official builds](http://windows.php.net/download).

Answer (score 1):

Your OS is 64-bits.
Your PHP version is x86.

How to determine the PHP version is using the constant

> PHP_INT_SIZE will return **4** for x86 version
>
> PHP_INT_SIZE will return **8** for x64 version

Related info:

> Doubleword: a 4-byte (32 bit) data item
>
> Quadword: an 8-byte (64 bit) data item

Hope that's clear :)