# IIS-Version-10 and Php 5.6 The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-10, php-5.6, windows-server-2022

Recently I am facing a new issue on my server, I get this error( 1 time a day) randomly anytime, and that time no one can able to login any module. Page are loading and loading until I restart IIS .lastly have been seen below error . Please check the error screenshot.

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.6/php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

**Most likely causes:**

IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

**Things you can try:**
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Someone suggest to install this Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4  32-bit version. But it is exists there . Someone please help me to solve this issue . My server environment at below...

**My Environment**
`Windows Server 2022 Standard 64Bit IIS Version 10.0.20348.1 Php version 5.6.31 32Bit MSSQL Server developer edition : 2017`

Regards,
Mozaffar

Yes I tried to solved but fail

Comment: PHP 5.6 x64 is very **old** and was marked as experimental ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870412/windows-php-64-bit-systems-atm), [2](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=334129#p1346058), [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20180106144019/http://windows.php.net/)). Try to use newer version at least PHP 7.4.

Comment: If you are using IIS x64 or x86 you must use the same with PHP and also install the same with VC++ Redis.

Comment: @vee In short, only PHP 8.x should be used https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php 7.4 is going to be deprecated in days. Another is that 32 bit PHP can work on IIS x64.

Comment: PHP 5.6 reached end of life a long while ago, so expecting it to work on Windows Server 2022 flawlessly is unrealistic. You will have to upgrade to a supported PHP release first and then the discussion can continue.

Comment: Thanks @vee and Lex  Li , I will update php version and let you know result

Comment: Yesterday I update PHP Version 8 instead of php 5.6 but today same issue raise as earlier .

Comment: Is your system 32 bit? For those who encounter this problem with PHP 5.6, they usually need the x86 version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (vcredist_x86.exe), the download link is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 Try reinstalling it might help.

Comment: @YurongDai ,My system is 64 Bit ,C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (vcredist_x86.exe) and (vcredist_x64.exe)  both already exists here .But today again same issue comes after 1 week gap

Comment: Since we were unable to reproduce your issue, the best approach is to use Failed Request Tracing, which provides key errors and warnings that will help you identify the issue. https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.