# PHP parse int wrong in XAMPP windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, parseint

demo

```
$code = '40001042901';
echo (int)$code; //intval($code) //same
```

I test on linux (Ubuntu) that result is 40001042901 but on windows result is 2147483647, what wrong with that?

XAMPP 1.8.3, PHP 5.5.15, Apache 2.4.10 (Win32)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - Read about overflowing.

Comment: because `$code = '40001042901' - value is a string

Comment: 64-bit software vs 32-bit software

Comment: @HoboSapiens, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces what is there to elaborate on? 32-bit systems => max int value is 2^31 -1 = 2147483647 == PHP_INT_MAX....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linux result is produced using 64-bit software. The Windows result comes from 32-bit software. The difference here is the maximum size of an integer, which in a 32-bit system is 2147483647.

When you try to parse the string to an integer the value is too large for a 32-bit value so PHP uses the largest available value.

In a 64-bit system integers can be much larger so PHP can use the actual value parsed from your string

Comment: +1 Apparently the problem still persists on windows x86_64 systems. Though [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837157) and [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058) answers point to the same somewhat [old piece of information](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/55886) and I'm not really sure, whether this has been fixed by now (e.g. in 5.5)...