# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers

Tags: php, xampp, dropbox-api

How can I solve the problem with this error? I am using xampp and php 5.5.6 for my application. My code is as follow:

```
<?php

`enter code here`# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "dropbox-php-sdk-1.1.2/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
$authCode = \trim(\readline("Enter the authorization code here: "));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

// uploading files
$f = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"], "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile($_FILES["file"]["name"], dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);`enter code here`
?>
```

When I run the script on my browser, I get this error.

Comment: Need a lot more detail than this - what does you code look like, what have you tried etc

Answer (score 1):

From the README:

> Requirements:
>
> - PHP 5.3+, [with 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php).