# Getting a 64-bit Unix Timestamp using 32-bit PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to timestamp database entries, but the MySQL native types don't seem sufficient (datetime because I want to be region independent, and timestamp because I want my code to work after the year 2038)

For this reason, I want to store a 64-bit unix timestamp in a MySQL bigint column. However, it seems that all the PHP timestamp functions return 32-bit integers on a 32-bit system (which I am running)

How can I get a 64-bit Unix Timestamp using 32-bit PHP?

Comment: Use DateTime objects, rather than unix timestamps

Comment: If you are worried about keeping your code working after 2038, then start making efforts to get it on a 64bit platform now, so you will know what the environment will be in 2038

Comment: After the year 2038 your server will be 128-bit, I'm sure.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php  
It seems that you *cannot* have a 64-bit integer in 32-bit PHP.  You'll need a non-integer representation of the timestamp.