# Error in connecting MS-Access database to PHP Server DSN-less

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I am new to PHP as well as new to Ms-access database. I am trying to connect php server to ms access database dsnless as i have to give this to my friend.  My both php file and ms database file are in same directory and they both are going to stay on localhost only. I am not able to understand the error.

I have 64 bit wamp version 2.4/Apache Version :2.4.4/PHP Version :5.4.16/ 64 bit windows 7
Also i have installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from official site.

Here is my php code

```
<?php
echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit<br/>";
$user = "";
$password = "";
$mdbFilename= "C:\wamp\www\test\testdb.accdb";

$conn=$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);              ////<----line 10

if (!$conn) {
  exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM testdb";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {
  exit("Error in SQL");
}

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
    $json_output[] = odbc_result($rs, "test");
    print(json_encode($json_output));

}
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is my error

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name., SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\test\working.php on line 10
```

Comment: Have you tried doubling up your '\' in the filespec.

Comment: Are you still running 32-bit PHP (as in your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26193598/2144390))?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes I am still running 32 bit version as 64 bit version is still experimental and not ready for commercial use.

Comment: @bohica Yes i did and this is how my path looked C:\\wamp\www\test\testdb.accdb but it didn't worked

Comment: Your example above only doubled the first \ and not all back slashes.

Comment: @bohica I did double all then backlash C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\test.mdb still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using to connect with a Ms-Access:

```
<?php
    $conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
    $dns = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".realpath("./youraccessdb.mdb").";";
    $conn->open($dns);
    $rs = $conn->execute("SELECT * FROM table");
    $field =  $rs->Fields(0);

    while (!$rs->EOF) {
      print $f1->value . "\n";
      $rs->MoveNext();
    }
    $rs->Close();
    $conn->Close();
?>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I am getting this error Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\test3.php on line 4

Comment: You have to add `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` to your php.ini to load the com/dotnet module.

Comment: I did that and now i am getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> Operation was canceled.' in C:\wamp\www\test\test3.php on line 6

Comment: i am getting two errors and this is second error com_exception: <b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> Operation was canceled. in C:\wamp\www\test\test3.php on line 6

Comment: this is line 6  $conn->open($dns);

Comment: Are you using Apache or IIS? Are you sure that the path of your DB it's ok?

Comment: I am using 64-bit wamp server. Path is exactly where the database and php server files are(both in same folder) but the biggest issue is it works when i use dsn but it doesn't work when i use dsn-less. Don't know why

Comment: @user3933143 `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` cannot read .accdb files. As the name indicates, it can only work with .mdb files. `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` can work with both.

Comment: @GordThompson I am getting same error even after changing to mdb and using new access files with mdb extension.