# string converted to int is too large

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I'm using `php-activerecord` to manage my MySQL entries.

The block of code where the problem ocurs is the following:

```
$item->id = $result->id;
$item->save();

var_dump($result->id); // string(10) "2386737351" 
var_dump($item->id);   // int(2147483647)
```

The problem is that `$result->id` is `string(10) "2386737351"` like it should, but `$item->id` becomes `int(2147483647)`. My column `id` is of type `BIGINT`, so no problem there.

It looks like `php-activerecord` converts that value to a int again which is capped at it's maximum value of 2147483647.

Obviously this is terribly wrong and causes `Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'unique'`.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: why would assigning a value to $item->id convert it to int? Is this *really* the code at cause? but nevertheless, can php really manage 64bit integers? I thought I heard someone comment it couldn't, and should manage such numbers as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BIGINT is being cast to an int because of the setting in `column.php`. While the "real solution" would be to run a 64 bit system, if you cannot, the other thing might be to just stop the cast from happening

Look at [line 37 in column.php](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Column.php#L37) , I suggest you change that. I haven't tried it myself, but I suppose that this does the trick:

```
'bigint'    => self::STRING,
```

Answer (score 1):

> Native 64-bit integers require 64-bit hardware AND the 64-bit version of PHP.
>
> On 32-bit hardware:
>   $ php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;' 2147483647
>
> On 64-bit hardware:
>   $ php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;' 9223372036854775807

As said by scotts on this question : [how to have 64 bit integer on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php)

So you have to use PHP 64bits version to use BIGINTs, else they will be automatically (or not and you will get an error) converted to integer.