# PHP 5.6.12 - Return of integer incorrect

Tags: php

Previously I have been developing an app using PHP 5.6.7 in Linux, however recently I've switched to a Windows environment using WAMP 64 bit and upgraded PHP to 5.6.12 and been running into a few issues. One issue is in the backend PHP I have an array of integers. When I print to return to the front which prints the return array to the console I get a different format. That is:

```
$permission->fk_org_id = [24053826281537536,24051529749102626,111];
print json_encode($permission->fk_org_id);
```

Returns the following to the console:

```
0:24053826281538000
1:24051529749103000
2:111
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you paste here result of `echo PHP_INT_MAX`?

Comment: Looks like they're converted to a float, but they are not too large for a 64-bit integer.

Comment: I did a print (PHP_INT_MAX) result is 2147483647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are too large to fit in a (32-bit) integer. They will be interpreted as a float, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow):

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

A [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) has a precision of about 14 significant digits, so that's why you see the zeroes.

Unfortunately, PHP on Windows does not support 64 bit integers, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233881/4751173):

> On windows x86_64, PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647. This is because in the underlying c-code, a long is 32 bit.
>
> However, linux on x86_64 uses a 64bit long so PHP_INT_MAX is going to be 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Thanks so what is the work around this? These numbers represents unique ids in my MySQL db.

Comment: Store them as strings, if you do not need to calculate with them, as I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for all comments. As I was running Windows via bootcamp, I ended up setting up XAMPP and ran my dev on osx. Shame but osx  supports 64bit integers, so happy.

Answer (score 1):

You probably run your script on 32-bit machine where max int is 2147483647, so integer overflow occurres. According to documentation:

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it
>   will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which
>   results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return
>   a float instead.

```
<?php
$large_number = 2147483647;
var_dump($large_number);                     // int(2147483647)

$large_number = 2147483648;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(2147483648)

$million = 1000000;
$large_number =  50000 * $million;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(50000000000)
?>
```

More about integers you can find in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow).

Comment: Thanks I'm running 64bit windows and 64bit WAMP server, should this be happening?