# Different result in phpMyAdmin and in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Actually i'm creating apps with CakePHP 3. The problems is that the result in phpMyAdmin and in CakePHP is not the same. When i retrieve table in phpMyAdmin i got something like this.

```
+-----+---------------+--------------+
| id  |      cin      |     nom      |
+-----+---------------+--------------+
| 17  | 123456789123  | TEST         |
| 16  | 102234566778  | MPANAOTEST   |
| 15  | 101256003054  | MIHARINTSOA  |
| 14  | 101253458255  | RAMAMONJISOA |
|  1  | 102256003063  | RAJAONAH     |
+-----+---------------+--------------+
```

And in my apps i got this

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  |    cin     |     nom      |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| 17  | 2147483647 | TEST         |
| 15  | 2147483647 | MIHARINTSOA  |
| 14  | 2147483647 | RAMAMONJISOA |
|  1  | 2147483647 | RAJAONAH     |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

My Controller looks like this

```
public function liste() {
    $this->set('employes', $this->Employes->find('all'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['employes']);
}
```

If someone can explain or give a way to fix it. Thanks

**Note**: CIN row is unique.

Comment: And the `cin` column is of type `*INT`, right?

Comment: @AD7six The values in the DB could indeed be different to what the OP expects, however seeing all the values ending up as `2147483647` when being read sounds more like a 32-Bit PHP that can't handle larger INTs.

Comment: CIN is unsigned big int

Comment: Yes PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely using a 32-Bit variant of PHP, the largest integer value it can handle is `2147483647`. What you are seeing is the expected result, CakePHP applies casting to the retrieved data depending on the column type, so in this case integer casting.

See **[Source > \Cake\Database\Type\IntegerType::toPHP()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.1/src/Database/Type/IntegerType.php#L62)**

Either switch to a 64-Bit PHP, or if that's not possible (or doesn't help [**for some reason**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233881/1392379)), change the column type. You wouldn't necessarily need to change the type in the DB, overriding the schema in your app would probably already help, something like

```
// ...

class EmployesTable extends Table
{
    protected function _initializeSchema(Schema $table)
    {
        $table = parent::_initializeSchema($table);
        $table->columnType('cin', 'string');
        return $table;
    }

    // ...
}
```

That way CakePHP would treat the column as a string type, and would be able to handle numbers larger than `PHP_INT_MAX` by treating them as strings. However this will also affect the marshalling process, the query builder, escaping, etc, you could for example end up with queries like

```
WHERE cin > '12345'
```

Even non numeric characters could slip in, so you might need to take additional measures to make sure that you are working with actual numbers.

I would suspect todays DBMS' query optimizers to be smart enough to handle (cast) this, however it's something one should be aware about.